# 1970s/1980s short story; aliens' emotions are visible in colours on their chest

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I assume it was originally 1970s - I think would have read it around 1981-3 - I was about 7, and its nearly 40 years ago, so apologies for the incredible vagueness.

I think it was a short story, though what book I cannot imagine - I suspect it might have been an actual comic strip, or more likely a short text story in a UK comic - like Eagle or 2000AD. I've gone through hundreds of those comics in that period, but no joy.

The Story: All I remember was it was a humanoid race of aliens where everyone except the elite constantly reveal their emotions via either their 'natural' chest, or some plate implanted. A main character is thus constantly revealing his pride or anger etc. The elites either have this 'plate' removed, or turned black so they are 'unreadable'.

Comment: See if anything here rings a bell: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LivingMoodRing

Comment: I got excited, thinking we already had this one before, only to realize that that was about a film where the chest lights indicated romantic compatibility.

Comment: Asimov's "What is this thing called love?" has aliens with color patches that reveal their emotion, but no mention of elites having their color organ removed

Comment: Eric Flint's Mother of Demons have aliens whose emotions are apparent from the color of their outer parts, but that's a novel and from 1997